# Mathematica Texture in Graphics3D becomes blurred

Tags: graphics3d, textures

I am using MMA to embed a series of 2D pics into a 3D graphics.
The code is as follows:

```
data = Table[
   ListLinePlot[Table[{n Cos[x], n Sin[x]}, {x, 0, 2 \[Pi], 0.5}], 
    PlotRange -> {{-5, 5}, {-5, 5}}], {n, 1, 5, 1}];
tab = Table[{Texture[data[[z]]], 
    Polygon[{{-1, -1, z}, {1, -1, z}, {1, 1, z}, {-1, 1, z}}, 
     VertexTextureCoordinates -> {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 
        1}}]}, {z, 1, 5, 1}];
plt = Graphics3D[{tab}, Lighting -> {{"Ambient", White}}]
```

However, the result I get is blurred (the ticks on axes cannot be seen) and I don't want the thick-black line in the middle.

How to achieve this?

[image]

Comment: You need to use `Rasterize[]` with appropriate `ImageResolution`/`RasterSize` settings before feeding to `Texture[]`. Don't count on `Texture[]`'s automatic conversion if you want  a good look.

Comment: Doesn't work really. Also, the thick-black line cannot disappear...

Comment: Your code on Mathematica 12.2 doesn't produce a thick axis line. [Image](https://ibb.co/Jpnb58s)

Comment: You might want to mention what version and OS you're on, because [it looks fine on my end](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ikeE4.png). (Version 12.2 on Windows 10)

Comment: ...and this is how you're supposed to use `Rasterize[]`: `Table[Rasterize[ListLinePlot[Table[{n Cos[x], n Sin[x]}, {x, 0, 2 π, π/6}], AspectRatio -> Automatic, AxesStyle -> AbsoluteThickness[2], PlotRange -> {{-5, 5}, {-5, 5}}, PlotStyle -> AbsoluteThickness[4]], "Image", ImageResolution -> 600], {n, 5}]`

Comment: Version21.1 does neither produce blur not a thick black line. Seems to be a bug that has been fixed